# what is the significance of auth attribute of datasources defined in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

In tomcat we define datasources. In datasources there is a attribute "auth". Generally i used to have its value equal to "container". for example.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myoracle" auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:mysid"
              username="scott" password="tiger" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
              maxWait="-1"/>
```

Can somebody please tell me what is the significance of this "auth" attribute? I could not find significance of this attribute after googling also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the [doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/globalresources.html) , it explains it :

> Specify whether the web Application code signs on to the corresponding resource manager programmatically, or whether the Container will sign on to the resource manager on behalf of the application. The value of this attribute must be Application or Container. This attribute is required if the web application will use a  element in the web application deployment descriptor, but is optional if the application uses a  instead.